# Logical operator in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I am trying to do different things based on the numbers.Right now *if condition* with *logical operator* is not working as I wanted to.
What is wrong with my code?

I have counter variable as counter which is incremented every time startSlider() function is called, and reset to 0(zero) if it greater than 15.

What I wanted to do is check if the counter variable is equal to a bunch of values on multiple if conditions.

Example: check if counter is equal to 1,2,3,4 and so on.

The problem I'am having is, the counter variable is not compared with every conditions on the right.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var foo = {
        interval        : 0,
        counter         : 1,
        pause           : 1000
    };
    function startSlider(){
        foo.interval = setInterval(function(){
            if(foo.counter>15){
                foo.counter = 1;
            }
            console.log(foo.counter);

            if(foo.counter === (1 || 7 || 9) ) {
                console.log('down');
            }else if(foo.counter === (2 || 3 || 4 || 11 || 10) ) {
                console.log('left');
            }else if(foo.counter === (5 || 6 || 13 || 14 || 15) ) {
                console.log('right');
            }else {
                console.log('up');                          
            }
            foo.counter++;
        },foo.pause);
    }   
    startSlider();
});
```

Here  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2kw943m/)

Comment: `not working as I wanted to` isn't much of a problem description.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is of no help either, did you try to run it? You need to add the HTML elements if you want to make it useable.

Comment: @Parker I think its helpful when you open up your console and see because in my code I console it to debug

Comment: helpful, but, certainly not any more helpful than a stack snippet would be.

Comment: Also note: what is actually happening here is you have, for example, `1 || 7 || 9` which is 1 *or* 7 *or* 9. Now since `1` is truthy, the whole expression evaluates as simply `1` so your `foo.counter === (1 || 7 || 9)` actually just becomes `foo.counter === 1`.

Comment: @MattBurland ok thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple numbers without comparing each of them to the variable.

```
if (foo.counter === (1 || 7 || 9) ) {
```

Should be:

```
if (foo.counter === 1 || foo.counter === 7 || foo.counter === 9) {
```

You can shorten it to something like this as well:

```
if (~[1, 7, 9].indexOf(foo.counter)) {
```

Comment: Why the downvote for a correct answer?

Comment: Another alternative would be to use a `switch` statement.